# What is the correct way in islam talk about for putting parent/caste name?

Tags: fiqh, naming

The question as the title suggest is self explainoty but I wanted to know what does islam say about putting father name infront of child name? Ususally in south asian (india, pakistan and bangladesh) the caste e.g. khan or malik is used next to kids name or    is used.

What is the correct way in islam talk about for putting parent/caste name next to kid male or female child?

Answer (score 2):

Allah the Almighty said:

> Call them by [the names of] their fathers; it is more just in the sight of Allah . But if you do not know their fathers - then they are [still] your brothers in religion and those entrusted to you. And there is no blame upon you for that in which you have erred but [only for] what your hearts intended. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful. ([33:5](https://legacy.quran.com/33/5))

Without looking into a tafsir or checking a book of fiqh we can already conclude the following:

- In Islam it is important to know the father of the child (which often is referred to as the biological father in this is what I mean when I use "father" in the following answer).
- The name of the father should be known.
- The child should be attributed to its father.
- This also means that if you intent to adopt a child you are not allowed to refer to it as yours, but the real father should be known. In the case described in the Qur'an Zayd ibn *Harithah*, was prior to the revelation of the corresponding verses known as Zayd ibn *Muhammad*, but Allah gave his orders, and Zayd was further on called by his fathers name, but he didn't go back to his father even if he was given the choice to do so. (See also in the [Sahih](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4782) hadith)
- On the other hand its not permissible for a child to claim being the son of anybody else than its own (biological) father. (See in the [Sahih](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6766))
- If the name is unknown this isn't the fault of the child.
- One can safely call a believing individual brother or sister in religion.
- This verse also made an end to the practice of Jahilya were a child was adopted and raised as an own child and called as such and had right to inherit from his adoptive parents.

It should be added that this verse is understood as referring to children of a legal marriage. Since the sunnah explains how to call children from adultery etc..

Further we could include from the above:

- It should be sufficient to know the name of a child's father and this can be achieved by any agreed upon ways or commonly used in your society.

For example even in some non-Muslim societies, and even if a woman loses her "family" name after marriage, in her identity documents you may find a reference of her birth name, which is a link to her father (so such a practice goes along with the requirement of the verse above). And in Muslims societies there are many different ways: Some of these have a created "surname", while they may be called with the name their parents give them followed by their father first name and so on, others may refer to you with your first name followed by "ibn" (son of) and the first name of your father, others again would differ, for example while you are unmarried they'll call you "abu" -in case of a man- (father of) followed by your father's first name (even if it is in fact exactly the opposite), once you'll have children you would be called "abu" followed by the name of your "son" and or "daughter". Others also have created surnames in western style, but in the legal identity documents father and or mother are documented. All these practices go along with the meaning of the verse.

As you may hopefully understand your question:
"What is the correct way in islam talk about for putting parent/caste name next to kid male or female child?" is subjective and you should chose the way that is practiced in your society, if it is in alignment to the conditions above. If the practice in your social environment doesn't give a hint of the child's father by any means it isn't halal to follow it